# Why my template directory being spit out from wp_head?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site in development that seems to be spitting out my template directory from wp_head. It's driving me crazy.

I inherited this site and I'm trying to make it work. I don't know what I should be looking for in the files.

here's the site in question: http://discoverthebody.ca/test/

Can anyone help with what I should look for?

**EDIT:** To clarify, in my header.php, I've narrowed down the error to happening here:

```
<!-- wordpress head functions -->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
<!-- end of wordpress head -->
```

The stray template directory call is being output right after that comment, so I assume wp_head() is where it's happening.

Comment: Are you talking about this path ??
http://www.discoverthebody.ca/test/wp-content/themes/discoverthebody

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui, yes that's the stray template directory that's being output... somewhere by the wp_head() function.

Comment: Moeed Farooqui, yes... and it's the parent theme's folder too... not the child theme.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what is it. I happened to notice that you have the plugin woo e-commerce enabled. I've noticed that plugin has really gone downhill lately, and tends to do a bunch of random stuff as well as not even work. Try disabling that plugin and seeing if it helps.

If it doesn't, try disabling your plugins one-by-one. If that doesn't fix it, look in `header.php` in your theme directory. for a stray link in the HTML.

Comment: It looks like it's in the wp_head() function that's it's happening, but as I understand it, it means it could come from anywhere, then... I'm not entirely sure how wp_head() works... either as a hook for other functions to add stuff or what.

Comment: Download [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and SSH into your server (credentials are the same as your FTP login. Make sure SSH is enabled in the CPanel). One logged onto your server, type `cd path/to/website` to change directories, and `ls` to see a list of files (so you can figure out where you are). Once you're in the correct place, type `grep -R add_[a-z]*\(.*wp_head *` to find a list of everything adding something to wp_head. For more information on SSH commands, read about [Linux commands](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0010.php)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've commented ALL instances of `wp_head` in my theme folder. Plug-ins shouldn't matter, if I disable them all, right?

Comment: @Armstrongest Correct

Answer (score 1):

if I was in your shoes I would do a site-wide search (ie `grep`) for one of these:

- bloginfo( 'template_directory );
- bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );
- get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
- get_template_directory_uri()
- TEMPLATEPATH

see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: Why not `grep -R add_[a-z]*\(.*wp_head *` to find all actions, filters, and anything else that's adding to wp_head?

Comment: I've searched the ENTIRE theme folder for `wp_head` and commented out all code that adds anything. Is there any other way to add to `'wp_head'` that doesn't involve `add_...` I'm going to check the plug-ins folder next, but if I disable all plug-ins it still appears. I've even done this on a completely fresh implementation of wordpress: `http://discoverthebody.ca/dev`

Comment: did you try grepping for my original suggestion?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text's Find in Folder, but yeah, I added the Regular expression there. It found 55 matches across 26 files. Extremely frustrating. There's no way of doing a stack trace, is there?

Comment: 55 matches for what, `TEMPLATEPATH`?